# Error Occurred:Invalid parameter value for: recipientIds

Tags: apex, visual-workflow

When I trie to debug my flow I get this error :  `Error Occurred:Invalid parameter value for: recipientIds`  and I get this in the Inputs : `recipientIds = {!RecipientIDs} ([])`

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm what you are adding to RecipientIDs . The screenshot is not showing it

Comment: @SaiPraveen Kakkirala this is what I add to the RecipientIDs  `{!$Record.Account_Name__r.Owner.Name} `

Comment: Can you try it to {!$Record.Account_Name__r.Owner.id}

Comment: @SaiPraveen Kakkirala ok , i will try it and makes you know the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_actions_sendcustomnotification.htm&type=5) For the recipientIds the accepted parameters are as follows in the flow.

The ID of the recipient or recipient type of the notification.

> 1. User ID—The notification is sent to this user, if this user is active.
> 2. Account ID—The notification is sent to all active users who are members of this account’s Account Team. Valid only if account teams are enabled for your org.
> 3. Opportunity ID—The notification is sent to all active users who are members of this opportunity’s Opportunity Team. Valid only if team selling is enabled for your org.
> 4. Group ID—The notification is sent to all active users who are members of this group.
> 5. Queue ID—The notification is sent to all active users who are members of this queue.

But in your flow you added owner Name instead of Owner id. Can you try adding the owner id as below.

```
 {!$Record.Account_Name__r.Owner.id}
```